# XML Errors using EPPlus to download Excel file in MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, epplus

Here is the important part, called from an AJAX call in the view:

```
 using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName);
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");
            Byte[] bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.End();
        }
```

But it creates an error:
[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What if you set some additional meta data like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123352/set-download-location-with-epplus ? Probably wont make a difference.  Maybe post more of your code.

Comment: @Ernie thanks. I tried that and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I answered this question but it had been moderated because of duplicating. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127060/why-the-borwser-cant-show-an-epplus-spreadsheet . I have an answer there. When that question has an accepted answer, I will perform dupplicated-marking. Now, it's impossible.