# Why the browser can't show an EPPlus spreadsheet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, epplus

I'm trying a lot of options with complete unsuccess. My need is create a spreadsheed in the server and the user gets it in the browser in a asp.net MVC 5 environment.

In the server the code is:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult ExportToExcel([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] Reports data)
    {
  ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
  var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample1");

  ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Sample 1";
  ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
  var shape = ws.Drawings.AddShape("Shape1", eShapeStyle.Rect);
  shape.SetPosition(50, 200);
  shape.SetSize(200, 100);
  shape.Text = "Sample 1 text text text";

  if (data.PDFFileName == null) data.PDFFileName = "Spreadsheet.xlsx";
  data.PDFFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(data.PDFFileName) + ".xlsx";

  FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(pck.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
  result.FileDownloadName = data.PDFFileName;
  return result;
}
```

**The view is**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Created Spreadsheet", "ExportToExcel", "GraphReport", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class="btn btn-warning" })
```

**The result in Chrome is:**

```
Remote Address:[::1]:49711

Request URL:http://localhost:49711/GraphReport/ExportToExcel

Request Method:POST

Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers

Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0

Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=Spreadsheet.xlsx

Content-Length:3561

Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Date:Mon, 29 Jun 2015 22:54:38 GMT

Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0

X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319

X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.2

X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbWNhc3Ryb1xEb2N1bWVudHNcVmlzdWFsIFN0dWRpbyAyMDEzXFByb2plY3RzXE1jU29mdFxDVlNcQmVlaGl2ZU1WQ1xHcmFwaFJlcG9ydFxFeHBvcnRUb0V4Y2Vs?=

Request Headers

Accept:*/*

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate

Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:31

Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

**The code is there in response:**

```
PKÓÝFCjkh'¬[Content_Types].xmlµÛN!_eÃ­Yh½0ÆtÛjb}f»¤ÂÐÃ¾½,[ij¢I{5?3ß?f½5Õ#iï6åV¡^i·jØûò©¾e%p
wØ°-æ³eª\ë¨a]JáNZ îº¬´>ZHyW"\Ã
```

Why it is not being interpreted as download attached file?

Comment: Nothing happens. The action is called, processed and returned. The return is the desired spreadsheet but the new View (the spreadsheet download) is not processed. The EPPlus example works, so application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet is understanded by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you cannot download file via AJAX call.

Solution: Create a form, use the POST method, submit the form. When the server page responds to the request, write a response header for the mime type of the file, and it will present a download dialog. You may need to use an `iframe` to prevent your site from navigating to error page if server returns an error.

Many of questions like this, they all have answers..

[Ajax call to download file returned from RESTful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955266/ajax-call-to-download-file-returned-from-restful-service)

[Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)